# Seaborn is plotting a line different from Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Following is the simple dataset =

```
x = [7.5, 7.5, 17.5]
y = [393.198, 351.352, 351.352]
```

The output plot I am looking for is correctly produced by -

```
plt.plot(x,y) #right angle looking plot
```

However, I get weird plot when I do this in Seaborn -

```
sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y)
```

I don't understand why Seaborn is producing this plot and how do I modify the Seaborn code to get the plot produced by Matplotlib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn try doing some estimation and sorting with the data for better visualization of the relationship between x and y ([document](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)).

The below code produce the same chart with matplotlib

```
sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y, estimator=None, sort=False)
```

Comment: Sure, but this is stupid as you use seaborn to just tell matplotlib to plot what you could plot directly… Useless use of seaborn here.

Comment: Maybe he's just curious and needs an explanation...

Comment: I have a feeling this is to benefit from the 'style' of seaborn, in which case this doesn't seem to be the right way to do it ;)

Comment: I do like the style of Seaborn, However, I try to use Seaborn wherever possible because it 1- plays nicely Pandas dataframes and 2 - has great support for statistical analysis 3 - rich API.

Comment: It does has nice support for statistical analysis, but when you disable all statistical options, then it's not needed ;) I love seaborn, but I use it when it it needed

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) is made to infer relationships between the x/y datasets. Thus it is computing an estimator (by default the mean) to **aggregate the data on common x**.

Here, as you have two times 7.5 as x, it aggregates the two points into a single y that is the mean of 393.198 and 351.352.

You're simply not using seaborn's function for what it is made. If you want the raw matplotlib graph, use matplotlib directly.

Comment: So, is there any way getting desired plot in seaborn? For now, I've achieved this by plotting 2 different line.

Comment: The question is, why do you absolutely want to use seaborn here? There is absolutely no point in doing so.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the functionality you mentioned so TIL something! You are right that for this particular scenario, no point in using Seaborn. However, in many many other scenarios, I've found Seaborn to be far better than Matplotlib.

Comment: You don't need to switch to matplotlib here you just need to put `estimator=None`.